# Matching multiple regexs on multiple lines passed as awk args

Tags: bash, awk

I'm trying to iterate through a large directory and run different regexs against each file to pull out the following data;

1. FileName
2. Pattern Matched
3. Line matched on
4. Number of occurrences

Thanks to @anubhava I was able to get a script that would search for one regex across multiple lines and return the data I needed.

I've since tried to adapt (and butchered) the script to match more than one regex in the file and return the data for all the regex's. I could potentially be looking for up to 8 regex patterns in one file.
I was trying to get it to work with the regex hardcoded in the script for now but eventually I would like to pass the regex patterns in as args to the script and run the match command against each pattern.

This is the awk script at the present but it is throwing the following error;

```
fatal: match: third argument is not an array+
```

Script;

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {print ARGV[1], "(Filename)"}
{
    RS = "\r?\n" 
    filemsg= "new File() Found on line "
    fismmsg= "FileInputStream Found on line "
   while(match($0, /new[[:blank:]]+File\(/, /FileInputStream/)) {
      nf = match($0, /new[[:blank:]]+File\(/)
      fis = match($0, /FileInputStream/)
      if (nf != ""){
        print filemsg NR
        ++n
      }
      else if (fis != "") {
        print fismmsg NR
        ++m
      }
      $0 = substr($0, RSTART+RLENGTH)
   }
}
/new[[:blank:]]*$/ {
   p = NR
   next
}
/FileInputStream/ {
  l = NR
  next
}
p && NF {
   if (/^[[:blank:]]*File\(/) {
      print filemsg p, "&", NR
      ++n
   }
   p = 0
}
l && NF {
   if (/FileInputStream/) {
      print fismmsg p, "&", NR
      ++m
    }
}
END {
   if (n > 0) {
     print n, "(number of occurrences of new File() pattern)\n"
   }
   else if (m > 0) {
     print m, "(number of occurrences of FileInputStream pattern)\n"
   }
   else {
     print "No occurrences of new File() or FileInputStream\n"
   }
}
```

I've no doubt I'm doing something really dumb.

Ideally I would pass each regex in as a var and iterate over the ARGV's to use in line where the hardcoded values currently are but that also raises the question on how would you split that arg to be able to use over multi line as we add the likes of ^[[:blank:]] to check for blank spaces on a line before the rest of the pattern.

***UPDATE***

Sample input would be;

```
awk -v regex1="new[[:blank:]]+File\(" -v regex2="FileInputStream" -v regex3="org\\.apache\\.commons\\.net\\.ftp\\."-f parameterisedRegexAWKScript.awk "$file" >> "output.txt"'
```

Sample output would be;

```
./modules/configuration/config/rules/somerule.gr (Filename)
No occurrences of new File() 

./modules/configuration/upgrade/contact/somecontact.gs (Filename)

No occurrences of new File() 

./modules/configuration/entity/someentity.gsx (Filename)
No occurrences of new File() 

./modules/configuration/FTP/newFileTest.txt (Filename)
new File() Found on line 15
new File() Found on line 18
new File() Found on line 28
new File() Found on line 37
new File() Found on line 53
5 (number of occurrences of new File() pattern)

./modules/configuration/FTP/test.txt (Filename)
new File() Found on line 3
new File() Found on line 4 & 8
new File() Found on line 10
new File() Found on line 10
4 (number of occurrences of new File() pattern)

./modules/configuration/personaldata/someperson.gs (Filename)
No occurrences of new File() 

./modules/configuration/processes/someprocess.gs (Filename)
No occurrences of new File() 

./originalAwkScript.txt (Filename)
new File() Found on line 6
new File() Found on line 29
new File() Found on line 32
3 (number of occurrences of new File() pattern)
```

***UPDATE 2***

Contents of test.tx

```
new
File()
new File()
new



File()
File() new
new File() test new File(Test)
FileInputStream
```

Contents of another sample file in the same folder;

```
    protected function buildDocumentsPath(documentRootDir : String, documentTmpDir : String) {
    if (DocumentsPathParameter.HasContent) {
      DemoDocumentsPath = getAbsolutePath(DocumentsPathParameter, documentRootDir)
      if (!new test 
      File(DemoDocumentsPath).equals(new File(DocumentsPathParameter))) {
          Logger.DOCUMENT.warn((typeof this).RelativeName)
          DocumentsPath = getAbsolutePath(DocumentsPathParameter, documentTmpDir)
          var file = new File(DocumentsPath)
          if (!file.exists() && file.isDirectory()) {
              file.mkdirs()
          }
      } 
    }

  }
```

But the input files could be any java class, nothing special about them.

Summary of requirement;
Essentially I'm trying to parse through a large directory using a bash command that uses an awk script to search for different regexs. Those regex's can occur over multiple lines in the classes and I need to capture all the data listed at the top of the question. I have different category of searches, so for example in FTP I'm looking for occurrences 'new File(', 'FileInputStream', 'org.apache.commons.net.ftp', java.nio.file', so there is a regex for each but there are other categories such as print (which has a different regex) etc.
So Ideally I want to be able to pass whichever regex I'm searching for into the awk script as params and store the retrieved data in a file.

Comment: @anubhava - I updated with expected inputs and outputs like requested, thanks

Comment: If you can reduce this to a [mcve] that just demonstrates **the problem you're asking for help** with (as opposed to just posting whatever large-ish script the problem occurs in) then we can help you.

Comment: @anubhava, I've provided some sample files to traverse but it could literally be any java class

Comment: @EdMorton, thanks. Sorry I appreciate I've probably overloaded the question with too much info so I've tried to provide a summary at the end of the second update of what I'm trying to achieve as opposed to how I'm attempting at present

Comment: Adding anything to it, even a summary, just makes your question longer when it was already too long. Reduce it to a [mcve] if you'd like help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message `match: third argument is not an array` means that you are calling the `match()` function with three arguments, and that the third one is not an array as expected.

This is the only call to `match()` with three arguments:

```
match($0, /new[[:blank:]]+File\(/, /FileInputStream/)
```

Judging by the next lines, you want to match either of the two regexes. Your line should then be:

```
match($0, /new[[:blank:]]+File\(|FileInputStream/)
```